# batch files copy to another folder, and overwrite files that shared partial name

Tags: bash

There are two folders, Folder A that contains a batch of log files, such as

```
Test10771_20181210141431.log
Test10771_20181210141431_141714370.jpg            
Test2062_20181210135223.log  
Test2118_20181210134852.log
```

There is another Folder B that contains another list of log files

```
Test10771_20181110142431.log
Test10771_20181110142431_141714370.jpg            
Test2062_20181010132223.log  
Test2118_20181010132852.log
Test3667_20181210142612.log 
Test8461_20181210134434.log
```

I would like to copy files from Folder A to Folder B, if `Test10771` exists in folder B, remove `Test10771_20181110142431.log` and `Test10771_20181210141431_141714370.jpg` in folder B, and copy  `Test10771_20181210141431.log` in folder A to B.

Comment: If the filenames are exact matches, a simple `cp` will do that.  But if you want to compare only the test number, do this:  loop on files contained in A (`for file in ...`_), extract the "TestNUMBER" from the filenames (`cut` or `sed`), check if you have files that have the same "TestNUMBER" in B (`if [ -f ...`), if yes, remove them (`rm B/TestNUMBER_*`), then copy the file from A to B.  Get started, it will not be done for you.  If you get stuck, research and last resort post here.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder_a="./FolderA"
folder_b="./FolderB"

while read -r line; do
    rm -f -- "$folder_b"/${line}*
    cp -p -- "$folder_a"/${line}* "$folder_b"
done < <(for i in "$folder_a"/*; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        filename="${i##*/}"
        prefix="${filename%%_*}"
        echo "$prefix"
    fi
done | sort | uniq)
```

After execution:

```
$ ls -1 FolderA
Test10771_20181210141431.log
Test10771_20181210141431_141714370.jpg
Test2062_20181210135223.log
Test2118_20181210134852.log

$ls -1 FolderB
Test10771_20181210141431.log
Test10771_20181210141431_141714370.jpg
Test2062_20181210135223.log
Test2118_20181210134852.log
Test3667_20181210142612.log
Test8461_20181210134434.log
```

- The procedure is performed in two steps.
- In the 1st step (for i .. loop), extract prefixes of the filenames in FolderA, and uniquify them.
- In the 2nd step (while .. loop), remove files in FolderB which matches with the prefix and copy files in FolderA to FolderB.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am running git bash and modify a little based on above code, and can obtain what I want. Thanks again